# Can I visit Betatakin in mid-May?

Tags: hiking, united-states, spring, national-monuments

The [Navajo National Monument website](https://www.nps.gov/nava/planyourvisit/upload/NAVA_S2-for-web-use.pdf) notes that Betatakin can only be visited on a ranger-guided tour.  It states that [groups leave daily](https://www.nps.gov/nava/planyourvisit/guidedtours.htm) between May 27 and September 3, and cliff dwellings are closed from October through April.  We will pass through the area May 13–14.  Is it possible to visit Betatakin during this period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to call and find out.

> Scheduling: Betatakin tours are free and available during the regular season, May 27, 2017– September 3, 2017, with a limit of 25 people per tour. All tours to Betatakin are on a first come, first serve basis. Reservations are not required. **Off-season will depend on weather conditions and available staffing. Please call (928)-672-2700 to confirm when tours are available.** If you represent a large group, please call in advance for possible accommodation

[Source](https://www.nps.gov/nava/planyourvisit/upload/Betatakin-Tour-Information-2017.pdf)